# Как в git'e отменить команду git init для папки?

Tags: git

Я случайно ее нажал и теперь не могу в ней клонировать репозиторий. OS: Win7, msysgit, tortoisegit.

Comment: удалить директорию `.git`?

Comment: а что именно ,какую команду прописать в консоле ,я пока с git только начал работать хочу понять ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удали папку в эксплорере, обычным способом. Ну или `rm -rf .git` если через `msysgit` консоль

Comment: в этой папке много других важных файлов ,просто так я ее удалить не могу ,пробывал создавать другую в нее переносить и потом переименовывать ее опять тоже не получается. Папка с названием localhost если названия поменять то локалка не поднимается.

Comment: опиши всё подробно. Что за директория, для чего используешь, есть ли какое-то ограничение прав. Что конкретно пытаешься сделать и какие конкретно ошибки получаешь.

Comment: папка home/localhost в этой папке хранятся другие проекты т.е сайты ,папка локального сервера. Т.е если переименовать то работать сайты через локалку не будут. Пробывал копировать папку localhost ,удалять старую и переименовывать не помогло. Ограничение прав нет ,ось винда. Ошибок тоже нет. Я просто хочу отменить для это папки git init ,потому что теперь в этой папке нельзя создавать других проектов. А создавать их в другом месте и переносить неохота.

Comment: просто удали директорию `.git`, она была сгенерированна `git init` и её наличие проверяет `git`.