# Git. Как откатить после git add *.c

Tags: git, git-add

Проходил обучение и выполнил команды:

```
$ git add *.c
$ git add README   
$ git commit -m 'initial project version'
```

`git add .README` завершилось ошибкой.

После этого при выполнении `git status`, выдает огромный список.

Возможно, это не проблема, если так, буду благодарен за простое объяснение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой сообщение перед простыней идет? Untracked files? (запустите `git status | less`, если вывод не помещается в буфер терминала). Скорее всего вы создали репозиторий с корнем прямо в домашней директории. Лучше так не далать.

Comment: @dzhioev: судя по заголовку командной строки, это и есть `~`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечая на поставленный вопрос — отменить все `git add ...` можно с помощью одной команды:

```
git reset .
```

---

В данном конкретном случае важно кое-что другое. 
Вы создали репозиторий гит в своей домашней директории, то есть `~` или `home`. Там он точно не нужен. Чтобы удалить его оттуда, просто удалите папку `.git` ([об этом есть целый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169493/181472)):

```
rm -r ~/.git
```

Потом создайте новую папку:

```
cd ~
mkdir learn_git
cd learn_git
# создаем репозиторий git
git init
```

Теперь в этой папке и проводите свои учебные эксперименты.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы очень помогли.

Comment: @DannyVin: пожалуйста! Спрашивайте ещё, когда будут вопросы.